# Python: Finding a "=" in a string

Tags: python

Using the python find function, I want to determine whether a string has an "=" sign in it.
It could find anything else other a "=".

`string: Math="Fun".`

`if (string.find("=") > -1):`

Any ideas?

Comment: The reason you're probably receiving negative votes is for asking a very simple question, without providing a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) of what you've tried.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with the `in` operator:

```
>>> "=" in "dog"
False
>>> "=" in "do=g"
True
```

There is no need to use `str.find()` (or the deprecated `string.find()`) to do this, unless you want to know the index of the character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` method directly on the string:

```
>>> "a = b".find("=")
2
```

Alternatively (though not as nice a method of doing so), you can use the `find` method on the `str` class:

```
>>> str.find("a = b", "=")
2
```

As Lattyware suggested, you ought to use the `in` operator over this method, unless you need the index.